# EnqueueWork doesn't start immediately on Oreo and above

Tags: android, android-workmanager, jobintentservice

in my SDK I use `JobIntentService` to do some work in background. I noticed that the job doesn't start immediately when I call `enquequeWork()`, but it starts some time later. I **can't** use `foreground service` to do the work, because the app can't run as foreground by client's request.
Is there any other way I can force the job to be done immediately after `enqueueWork()` is called?
I also use `WorkManager`'s `PeriodicWorkRequest` to check if the work can be done, every X minutes and if so, I call for the `JobIntentService` and enqueue the work I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other way I can force the job to be done immediately after enqueueWork() is called?

No. `JobIntentService` uses `JobScheduler`, and `JobScheduler` runs jobs when it decides to.

> I also use WorkManager's PeriodicWorkRequest to check if the work can be done, every X minutes and if so, I call for the JobIntentService and enqueue the work I need.

You might consider simplifying your code and just do your work in your `Worker`, if the only supplier of work to the `JobIntentService` is this `Worker`. Or, have the actual "work" be performed by a class that can be used by either your `Worker` or your `JobIntentService`. Just as `JobIntentService` uses `JobScheduler`, so does `WorkManager`. Your current system appears to have a job just trigger another job, and you could reduce latency by consolidating those.